# Absolutely-positioned menu drawn beneath relative-positioned div beneath it

Tags: html, css

## The setup, simplified

I realized that my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61084615/css-relatively-positioned-div-covering-up-clicks-on-absolute-just-above-it) from earlier was inaccurate. I decided to reproduce my problem to ensure I'm describing the situation as well as possible:

https://jsfiddle.net/wheresmycookie/gjd12pyz/49/

`.hint__horizontal` is a relatively positioned green line that is 1px high and contains an absolute-positioned anchor inside of it.

`.container__section` is a block for text that is relatively positioned. It's directly beneath hint-horizontal.

## The problem

`.container__section` seems to be position on top of the menu. In the link above, the section is highlighted gray. Notice that you can't click on the menu until it passes `.container_section`.

## Question

It seems like, because `.hint__horizontal` was rendered before `.container__section`, all of the absolutely-positioned children are rendered underneath `.container__section`. What would be the best way to ensure that the menus are always positioned on top?

Comment: increase z-index of .hint__horizontal

Comment: @TemaniAfif OMG thank you!!! I did not realize that relatively-positioned things could have a z-index. If you post as an answer I'll upvote!

Comment: z-index works on all the postionned elements (even relative one)